# Magento: Language detection and url 404 error

Tags: php, magento

I've configured my magento index.php so it detects the browser language and redirects the user to the corresponding store view. That works fine. But there is a problem with this with url specific for each store view. For example, a have a product with the url:

```
./product-url-in-english --> English view
./product-url-in-catalan --> Catalan view
```

If my browser is configured in English and I go to the Catalan url, then I got a 404 error, because that url is only for the Catalan view, but given that I'm detecting the browser language and redirecting to the English view, the Catalan URL won't work.

If I use the paramenters from_store and store, it will work, but I don't know how to reflect that on my index.php file. The code that detects the browser language is the following:

```
/* Language detection */
function getLanguageCode()
{
    $default_language_code = 'es';
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])) {
        foreach (explode(",", strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])) as $accept) {
            if (preg_match("!([a-z-]+)(;q=([0-9.]+))?!", trim($accept), $found)) {
                $langs[] = $found[1];
                $quality[] = (isset($found[3]) ? (float) $found[3] : 1.0);
            }
        }
        // Order the codes by quality
        array_multisort($quality, SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_DESC, $langs);
        // get list of stores and use the store code for the key
        $stores = Mage::app()->getStores(false, true);
        // iterate through languages found in the accept-language header
        foreach ($langs as $lang) {
            $lang = substr($lang,0,2);
            if (isset($stores[$lang]) && $stores[$lang]->getIsActive()) 
                return $lang;
        }
    }
    return $default_language_code;
}


/* Store or website code */
if(isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']))
    $mageRunCode = $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'];
else
    $mageRunCode = getLanguageCode();

/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';

Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

What do I need to change in my index.php file so I can handle url from all the store views and redirect to the specific page without getting a 404 error?

Thanks